# MongoDB authorization on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: configuration, authentication, mongodb

I installed MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.04. I create a `systemd` service to start `mongo` with the following exec:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

All the options in my config file are working except for the security: authorization: enabled. When I enable this and try to start the mongo service the service will not start. I comment out auth and it starts without issue.

I found an article that says you should add the `--auth` option to the ExecStart in the mongo service like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

When I enable auth this way it works, but enabling that option in the config file does not. Can somebody explain why auth only seems to work in the ExecStart line of the service and not in the config file?

The MongoDB documentation says this should work in the config file.

Comment: If you could post the contents of your log files with an example failed start in them it would be very helpful in terms of figuring this out

Answer (score 0):

If you don't participate in any mongodb cluster then your security settings in configuration file should be:

```
security:
#    keyFile: "/data/key/rs1.key"
    authorization: "enabled"
```